# What the difference between these two SQL queries?

Tags: sql

**QUERY 1:**

```
SELECT Frequents.drinker FROM Frequents 
WHERE Frequents.drinker NOT IN (    
SELECT F.drinker FROM Frequents AS F 
WHERE F.bar NOT IN  
(   
    SELECT bar FROM Sells, Likes WHERE Sells.beer = Likes.beer AND Likes.drinker =  F.drinker   
)    
)
```

**QUERY 2:**

```
 SELECT Frequents.drinker FROM Frequents, Sells, Likes 
 Where Frequents.drinker = Likes.drinker and Sells.bar IN(
     SELECT bar from Sells where Sells.beer = Likes.beer)
```

**Relation Schema**

[image]
Note: Ignore spellings mistakes.

> Which of the above query is correct for "Print the drinkers that
>   frequent only bars that serve some beer they like. (Assume each
>   drinker likes at least one beer and frequents at least one bar.) "

Answer (score 0):

Q1 finds drinkers that drink in bars that sells beer.

Q2 finds drinkers that do not drink in bars that do not sell beer.

It may, but doesn't necessarily, mean the same thing.

Is this an assignment?

Comment: Q1 is the solution to an assignment and Q2 is what i submitted and i believe my version of query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first SQL statement seems to select Frequent drinkers that go to bars that don't server their preferred beer.

The second SQL statement lists frequent drinkers that go to bars that do sell their preferred beer.